# Possible to show and edit database records in same view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple admin view that displays all the possible quests. I want to make it possible that the admin can see all the quests and have the possibility to edit each one of them on the same view. I have a table with all my quest data and an edit button for each record.

The edit part for each quest should be displayed on the right side of the table.

**I'm not sure how to get each correct quest item to the edit part of the view when the edit button for that record has been clicked**.

Is it possible to do this with just laravel and blade?

**My view**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>ADMIN PANEL</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($quests as $questIndex => $quest)
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{($questIndex + 1)}}</th>
                <td>{{$quest->name}}</td>
                <td>No price set</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Edit</a><a class="btn btn-outline-dark"> Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach  
            </tbody>
            </table>
            {{$quests->links() }}
        </div>
        // edit the quest here 
        <div class="col-md-4 collapse" id="collapseExample">
             <p> Edit the quest </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**My controller**

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $quests = Quest::simplePaginate('20');
        return view('admin.index', compact('quests'));
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can do this.  If you want to keep it on the same blade you could do a modal popup for edit and then when done with the editing send it back to the contorller and store all of your changes in the DB.  And once done with the edit you can return redirect to the route that hits your index method

Comment: A modal would be a pretty good solution, but I would prefer to use the extra whitespace I have on the page. The main problem I'm facing is to actually send the data from the edit button to the other edit part of the view.

Comment: you'll send it back to the controller where it will update the db, then from there redirect to whatever route the index is at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments there are several ways to do this.

**Method 1:**

Using a simple route without using ajax (which would be a bad practice in my opinion)

Routes.web

```
Route::post("editQuest", "MyControllerQuest@editQuest")->name("editQuest");
```

*.blade.php

Then you would open the modal as pointed in the comments and then have a button called `Make changes`.

```
<form action="{{ route("editQuest") }}">
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="quest_id" value=""> // You would need to update this value whenever a user clicks on the button to edit the record with the id of the quest
  <button type="submit">Make Changes</button>
</form>
```

then in ´MyControllerQuest` you would do the changes and redirect user back to the previous page.

**Method 2:**
You could make an ajax call to make the change. I won't write a full answer covering that topic because this is out of the scope of the question but you could follow this link (1st link at Google) [Laravel and ajax](https://appdividend.com/2018/02/07/laravel-ajax-tutorial-example/)

**Advantages of method 2:**
By making the changes via an ajax you won't have to load the entire page again thus saving the server of having to get the 20 records which you are paginating

Happy coding!

Comment: The main problem i'm facing is that I don't know how to get the correct data in my modal. I need the information of my list item in my modal when the edit button gets clicked. I basically want  2 input fields with the old values within the input fields

Comment: You would need to use javascript (or a library like jQuery) to get the data and insert them into your modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for values for **$quests** in blade and call same view from both functions (edit and index) e.g.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
 <h2>ADMIN PANEL</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @if( isset($quests) && count($quests) )
           @foreach($quests as $questIndex => $quest)
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{($questIndex + 1)}}</th>
            <td>{{$quest->name}}</td>
            <td>No price set</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Edit</a><a class="btn btn-outline-dark"> Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach  
          @else
            //content for index page
          @endif
        </tbody>
        </table>
        {{$quests->links() }}
    </div>
    // edit the quest here 
    <div class="col-md-4 collapse" id="collapseExample">
         <p> Edit the quest </p>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
  @endsection
```

Or you can set that condition before table if want to have content other than table for index page.

Hope this helps